# net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["geonames"] is not a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to pull data from json sample url http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo via HTTP transformation and then using java transformation to parse it.

In java transformation i am giving below code:

```
    //converting the input stream HTTPOUT into JSON object   

    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(HTTPOUT);   

    //Initializing JSON Array 'geonames'    

    JSONArray  geonames  = json.getJSONArray("geonames");   

    //Looping through all the Array objects   

    for (int i = 0; i < geonames.size(); ++i) {

        //Getting JSON Objects from the Array

        JSONObject geoname = geonames.getJSONObject(i);

        String lng = geoname.getString("lng");
        lngOUT=lng;
        String geonameId = geoname.getString("geonameId");
        geonameIdOUT=geonameId;
        String countrycode = geoname.getString("countrycode");
        countrycodeOUT=countrycode;
        String name = geoname.getString("name");
        nameOUT=name;

    // Generating rows in informatica 

      generateRow();  
    }
```

List of jar files:

```
commons-io-2.4.jar;
commons-logging-1.2.jar;
commons-lang-2.6.jar;
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar;
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar;
commons-lang3-3.1.jar;
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
```

In Import packages section I have given below packages.

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.lang.String;
    import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
    import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
    import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
```

In java class path I have mentioned all the external jar files used.
ETL job is getting failed for below error:

```
Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762
Message: [ERROR] net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["geonames"] is not a JSONArray.at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:2038)
at com.informatica.powercenter.server.jtx.JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.execute(JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:161)
```

Comment: Please Show the json

Comment: if i call your link, i get the following Json object: `{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}`. Which does not conatin an element named `geonames`

Comment: I am not sure... I am able to open the link.... let me share the data set with you...

Comment: {"geonames":[{"lng":-99.12766456604,"geonameId":3530597,"countrycode":"MX","name":"Mexiko-Stadt","fclName":"city, village,...","toponymName":"Mexico City","fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City","lat":19.428472427036,"fcl":"P","population":12294193,"fcode":"PPLC]}

Comment: What HTTP Status code does your service receives when doing the call?

Comment: Its GET request

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

your geonames value doesn't seem to be  valid. 
check the positions of opening and closing square brackets and curly braces. 
do they appear to be valid JSON? 
fix the brackets as shown here and then run it.

{"geonames":**{[**"lng":-99.12766456604,"geonameId":3530597,"cou‌​ntrycode":"MX","name‌​":"Mexiko-Stadt","fc‌​lName":"city, village,...","toponymName":"Mexico City","fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City","lat‌​":19.428472427036,"f‌​cl":"P","population"‌​:12294193,"fcode":"P‌​PLC]}